# How to delete a selected document.Comment

Tags: c#, ms-word, comments, vsto

There are a few comments in a Word document. After highlighting one, I'd like to delete it. I can loop through all comments. How to know which comment is selected?  I wrote code below but `document.Comments[i].Reference.Start` seems not really exist.

```
MSWord.Document document = ThisDocument.Instance.InteropDocument;
try
{
    DocumentProtector.Unprotect(document);
    for (int i=1; i<=document.Comments.Count; i++)
    {
        MSWord.Range r = document.Comments[i].Reference;
        if (document.Application.Selection.Range.Start == document.Comments[i].Reference.Start)
            document.Comments[i].Delete();
    }
}
finally
{
    DocumentProtector.Protect(document);
}
```

Comment: Dealing with Selection is finicky because you have to depend on exactly how the user clicked. For now, try using this as a condition for deleting the comment. The comment's text itself needs to be selected, however its a start:if(document.Comments[i].Range.InRange(document.Application.Selection.Range))

Comment: I think we need to use the Comments.Scope as well. I'll take a look at this tomorrow, but let me know your thoughts in the meantime.

Comment: Can you post what worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

use [`Range.InRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff822960) method:

> Returns True if the range to which the method is applied is contained in the range specified by the Range argument.